# Google analytics service not received pages from iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios7, google-analytics

overflow. Perhaps somebody can help me. I have the next problem:
The next code i am using for sending my analytics events to google analytics:

```
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:trackerID];
     [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:authenticationState()
                                                          action:fullPath(event)
                                                           label:paramStringFromParams(params, NO)
                                                           value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]] build]];
```

This event sending successfully and received by google ... At the next method i am sending the page:

```
 id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:trackerID];

    [tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:strSend
                                                      forKey:kGAIScreenName] build]];
```

This sending successfully too. But it's page(or view) not received by google analytics service. Please, any help me? [Sorry for my English] [P.S. Service working is correctly]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to send page views:

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
           value:@"Home"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```